# Problema cuando quiero hacer un post o get de usuarios

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Javascript,Node.js y Express.
Estoy tratando de hacer toda la lógica del usuario pero por algún motivo no quiere funcionar. El error que postman me tira es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot POST /users/</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Este es el código del modelo para un usuario

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String,
  username: { type: String, minlength: 5, maxlength: 50, required: true },
  mail: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 255,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: { type: String, minlength: 5, required: true }
});

/* Create the model from the schema. */
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Después tengo una carpeta routes que tiene una carpeta users que tiene 
un index.js

```
const checkAuth = require('../../middlewares/check-auth.js');
const handlers = require('./handlers');
const validators = require('./validators');

module.exports = router => {
  router.get('/users', checkAuth, validators.find, handlers.find);
  router.post('/users', validators.create, handlers.create);
  router.get('/users/:id', checkAuth, validators.find, handlers.findById);
  router.put('/users/:id', checkAuth, validators.update, handlers.update);
  router.delete(
    '/users/:id',
    checkAuth,
    validators.deletion,
    handlers.deletion,
  );
  return router;
};
```

Handlers.js

```
const User = require('mongoose').model('User');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const find = (req, res) => {
 ...
};

const findById = (req, res) => {
 ...
};

const generateToken = tokenData => {
  ...
};

const create = (req, res) => {
  ...
};

const update = (req, res) => {
  ...
};

const deletion = (req, res) => {
  ...
};

module.exports = {
  find,
  findById,
  create,
  update,
  deletion,
};
```

validator.js

```
const { celebrate, Joi } = require('celebrate');

const find = celebrate({
  ...
});

const findOne = celebrate({
  ...
});

const create = celebrate({
 ...
});

const update = celebrate({ ... });
const deletion = celebrate({ ... });

module.exports = {
  find,
  findOne,
  create,
  update,
  deletion,
};
```

Y ademas otro index para cargar la ruta usuario y otras que tengo.

```
const markers = require("./markers");
const users = require("./users");

const resourceRoutes = [markers, users];

module.exports = router => {
  resourceRoutes.forEach(routes => routes(router));
  return router;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede que este mal definido la consulta POST en postman.

Recuerda en los `Headers` poner `Content-Type` y en el lado derecho `application/json`. En segundo lugar escribir bien la ruta `http://127.0.0.1/users` y finalmente agregar el body de la consulta:

```
{
  "username": "username1",
  "mail": "prueba@prueba.com"
  "password": "mi password 123" 
}
```

Recuerda que al seleccionar en postman el metodo POST tienes que ir a `body` luego seleccionar la opcion `raw` y elegir `JSON (application/json)`

Si tienes un puerto en la URL tambien debes agregarlo (`http://127.0.0.1:3000/users`)

Ahora, si no te funciona ninguna ruta entonces no están siendo declaradas.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Voy a intentar corregir eso mismo !!